# SQL query to LINQ left outer join

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I need help with converting a SQL query to LINQ. I tried with Linqer but that didn't give the expected results. This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
    dr.startDate,
    dr.endDate,             
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.Size <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FirstGroup,
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.Size > 10 AND me.Size <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SecondGroup,
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.Size > 20 AND me.Size <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ThirdGroup,
    SUM(CASE WHEN me.Size > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FourthGroup,
    MAX(ISNULL(me.Size,0)) AS MaxSize,
    SUM(ISNULL(me.Size,0)) AS SpaceTotal
FROM
    time_intervals dr
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rooms me
ON ( me.DateTime BETWEEN dr.startDate AND dr.endDate)
GROUP BY
    dr.startDate,
    dr.endDate
ORDER BY dr.startDate
```

The LINQ i tried is:

```
  var stats = from t in time_intervals
       from q in query
       where q.DateTime >= t.startDate && q.DateTime <= t.endDate

       select new { 
          Date = t.startDate, 
          First = (q.Size <= 10), 
          Second = (q.Size > 10 && q.Size <= 20), 
          Third = (q.Size > 20 && q.Size <= 30), 
          Fourth = (q.Size > 30)
         };
```

But that didn't give the same result as the SQL query.

Comment: The LINQ i provide is just for testing, i know there are more columns which query is returning

Comment: Did you try [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com)?

Comment: yes, could not convert it to LINQ

Comment: I don't want to get kicked off Stack, but why do so many folk want to convert SQL to linq, so linq can generate back into SQL. Linq covers a fairly tiny subset of what you can do in SQL. Say you could convert this query, maybe tomorrow you'd want to modify it, and linq couldn't handle the modification. If you've got good SQL, why not just keep it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using group keyword in your LINQ while you are grouping records by by start date and end date.
Try this code:-

```
            var stats = (from t in time_intervals
                        from q in query.Where(m=> m.DateTime >= t.startDate && m.DateTime <= t.endDate).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        group q by new { t.startDate, t.endDate, q.Size } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Date = g.Key.startDate,
                            First = g.Count(m=>m.Size <= 10)
                        }).OrderBy(m => m.startDate);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's not valid. g.Count(m=>m.Size <= 10), there isn't m.Size, it is only getting two columns from time_intervals startDate and endDate

Comment: Swap "group t" to "group q". It will work fine. if problem still retains, write here.

Comment: Nope, it gives this message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Cannot Sum bool expression

Comment: The DefaultIfEmpty() is returning null and thats why there is error: "Object reference not set...."

Comment: ok. then try after remove that DefaultIfEmpty(). and let me know if it's working.